# iOS: Get users location

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-location

I'm making an app to share location. The user sends to some friends a permission to be tracked, and then they will be able to see where the user is. 
How to do that? I only find how to track the device itself (the user see where he is), how to track another devices (the user see where other users are)?

Comment: Your question is too general. There are so many ways to do what you suggest. Usually you would be saving each user's location at a specific time in a database and retrieve it for the other users when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make sure I got it right:

Suppose your app is installed on three iPhones (A and B).

The owner of A has B as friend.

Your app has a button "allow tracking". This button invokes an action that send a message to friends that tracking is ok.

For A it means tracking by B is ok.

Correct? 
(my solution!)
If so, then you would need a server that handles all that.

The server has to manage friendships and store location of the (registered) user.

The workflow would be as follow.

- A and B register within the app -> sendregistration to server
- A marks B as friend -> send friendship to server
- A marks that B can track -> send tracking-allow to server
- A updated location -> send new location to server
- B checks for A's location -> query server for A's location
- B receives location from server -> display location in app

Comment: Hum, thanks! i had thought this way, but i was wondering if it could be done anyhow directly with core location or other framework.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this - you'll have to have a server that saves the friend's location.  This will require using a database to store the information and then writing a service on the server to fetch the information from the iPhone application.  You could look to solutions like Amazon EC2 and Amazon SimpleDB to make this easier for you.

Other than that - your question is too general for a specific answer.

Comment: Sorry, i tried to make the question as direct and specific as possible. However that was my doubt, i was looking a way to do that without this server solution, something more direct, but now i know the way. Thanks!